# Why does python shelf module give an error at start up when opening file

Tags: python, encoding, import, raspberry-pi3, shelve

I have been using the python shelf module to store face encodings from the python face-recognition module below. I did this to make the live image recognition process faster.

I then imported these encodings in another script using the shelf module again, assigned them to a variable, and use them further down my script. This all works fine in the python idle environment and when I run it from the terminal. However, on startup, the shelf module fails to import the data. Can anyone tell me why this happens at start-up? The error I get on the log file is below. I have been stuck on it for a few days now. Is there a better way of storing and reusing the encodings? Thanks in advance.

### the bit of code that fails on start-up but runs fine otherwise

```
import shelve

shelfFile = shelve.open('face_encodings')

known_encodings = shelfFile['known_encodings']

known_names = shelfFile['known_names']

shelfFile.close()
```

### the error on startup

```
Traceback (most recent call last):   File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shelve.py", line 111, in __getitem__
value = self.cache[key]  
KeyError: 'known_encodings'
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "/home/pi/Desktop/run/testing.py", line 4, in <module>

    known_encodings = shelfFile['known_encodings']

  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/shelve.py", line 113, in __getitem__

    f = BytesIO(self.dict[key.encode(self.keyencoding)])

KeyError: b'known_encodings'
```

### face-recognition module

https://pypi.org/project/face-recognition/